# How can I organise the layouts to get an interface like this?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

How can I have an interface like this. I tried but I had a bad interface. I couldn't organize the layout and especially the round borders knowing that I didn't need the title of the fragment above. So I need your help please
thanks in advance

[image: layout]

Comment: You can use cardview to get rounded borders.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [TabActivity](http://www.viralandroid.com/2015/09/simple-android-tabhost-and-tabwidget-example.html) as main activity, and create [Fragments With Tabs](http://www.truiton.com/2015/06/android-tabs-example-fragments-viewpager/). In one Fragment create [RecyclerVeiw with CardView](http://www.journaldev.com/10024/android-recyclerview-and-cardview-example-tutorial). In the CardView you can create any layout.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use [CardView](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html) and there is a good and complete tutorial for CardView [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-recyclerview-and-cardview-on-android--cms-23465).

And you can use TabView for some part of that view. And [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/) is a good tutorial for TabView.